# Settings for the resolution of intersecting object outlines

Tags: 3d-view

after I scaled my model up by factor 100 the outlines where two objects meet appear ragged. They only get smooth when I zoom way in. Is there a setting where I can adjust this, and if yes, where do I find it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Usually the camera clip values

Comment: There is no camera involved though